# Media Player Fragement Crashes

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-mediaplayer, shoutcast

You may have seen that I have had a problem with creating a Media Player a few months back. Well I am trying to get to the next stage by getting it to work in a fragment but the app keeps on stopping/crashing on me. Can someone help me please? Here is my activity/fragment (code-behind) class

```
public class MediaPlayerNew extends Fragment implements 
android.media.MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener, 
android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener,
android.media.MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener,          
android.media.MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener{

private MediaPlayer mp = null;
private String TAG = getClass().getSimpleName();
private Button play;
private Button pause;
private Button stop;
private TextView txtVStatus;

public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_player, container, false);

    return view;
}

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    play = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnPlay);
    pause = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnPause);
    stop = (Button) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    //status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtVStatus);

pause.setEnabled(false);
stop.setEnabled(false);

play.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        play();
    }
});

pause.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        pause();
    }
});

stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View view) {
        stop();
    }
});
}

private void play() {
    //HTTP to BCRFM STREAM
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse("http://37.187.193.36:8002");
    try {
        if (mp == null) {
            this.mp = new android.media.MediaPlayer();
        } else {
            mp.stop();
            mp.reset();
        }
        mp.setDataSource(myUri.toString()); // Go to Initialized state)
        mp.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mp.setOnPreparedListener(this);
        mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(this);

        mp.setOnErrorListener(this);
        mp.prepareAsync();

        Log.d(TAG, "LoadClip Done");
    } catch (Throwable t) {
        Log.d(TAG, t.toString());
    }
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(android.media.MediaPlayer mp) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Stream is prepared");
    final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtVStatus);
    textViewToChange.setText("Welcome to BCRfm");
    mp.start();
    play.setEnabled(false);
    pause.setEnabled(true);
    stop.setEnabled(true);

}

private void pause() {
    mp.pause();
    final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtVStatus);
    textViewToChange.setText("You have paused your feed to BCRfm");
    play.setEnabled(true);
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(true);
}

private void stop() {
    mp.stop();
    final TextView textViewToChange = (TextView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.txtVStatus);
    textViewToChange.setText(" ");
    play.setEnabled(true);
    pause.setEnabled(false);
    stop.setEnabled(false);

}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    stop();
}

public void onCompletion(android.media.MediaPlayer mp) {
    stop();
}

public boolean onError(android.media.MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Media Player Error: ");
    switch (what) {
        case android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK:
            sb.append("Not Valid for Progressive Playback");
            break;
        case android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_SERVER_DIED:
            sb.append("Server Died");
            break;
        case android.media.MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_UNKNOWN:
            sb.append("Unknown");
            break;
        default:
            sb.append(" Non standard (");
            sb.append(what);
            sb.append(")");
    }
    sb.append(" (" + what + ") ");
    sb.append(extra);
    Log.e(TAG, sb.toString());
    return true;
}
public void onBufferingUpdate(android.media.MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
    Log.d(TAG, "PlayerService onBufferingUpdate : " + percent + "%");
}
}
```

Comment: If you crash, you should post the Logcat error, that would help.

Comment: Don't initialise your views inside onCreate, Fragment is not as Activity. Do those inside onCreateView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are issues with your code, and I will number them for clarity.

**1)**  With methods `onCreateView` and `onCreate`, at least (check others!), place the keyword `@Override` above the methods declaration. Please compare sample codes in Google.
Failure to do this and perhaps the compiler would not consider it as overriding.

**2)**  There is nothing wrong with

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

This is normal code.

**3)**  Change from:

```
 @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
      super.onDestroy();
}
```

TO:

```
 @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
     stop();
     super.onDestroy();
}
```

The main difference is calling `stop()` before `onDestroy()` call. When you're destructing, it's standard to call destroy/destruct after all the other codes.
And...you *should stop the Media Player*, otherwise it will still keep playing whatever even after the app exits.

Comment: Hi @the original android and thanks for your comment. I'd like to keep the media player active in the background until the person exists the app. Reason been encase the user still wants to listen into the station. Is it okay if i ask you a q, or two? Do you know a way to see if the user has the internet active before activating the media stream? Secondly, I know I'll have to receive revert this to another q and all, but do you know of any good for examples if how to create a media controller in the notification area.

Comment: @PatrickMelia, You should posts more questions for them. Here in SO, we like to share the questions/answers to developers. If you think my post is useful since you responded, you may upvote my answer. I noticed your comment says to the effect you want the Media Player to be active in the background, that is not what your post says, which makes the entire post not useful to the public.

Comment: sorry I didn't mean to add that line to the comment. So your ans is correct.

Comment: @PatrickMelia, Thank you for your thoughts. You may also upvote my posted answer. It is located on the left side of this post, with the big up-arrow icon, and click on it. This actually increases rep points, thanks. Pls read the SO tutorial @ http://stackoverflow.com/tour . You get rep points by reading it.

Answer (score 0):

Its okay, I fixed it.

I changed:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);......
```

to

```
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);..
```

And it works perfectly, only thing is when I want to switch from this fragment to another, the app crashes. Any tips?

**Fixed it**

Changed

```
 @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
  stop();
}
```

to

```
 @Override
  public void onDestroy() {
  super.onDestroy();
}
```

Comment: It's good that you think you fixed it. But it seems that you made workaround fixes. I'll post an answer based on your answer.